# error in working sqlite3 on ubuntu server

Tags: python, sqlite, ubuntu, peewee

I use orm peewee in my project. When run on a local machine, it works fine, but when I upload ubuntu 18.4 to the server, it starts to give this error:

```
SQLite does not support specifying which values to preserve or update.
```

Python==3.6.9
Peewee==3.14.8

All manipulations on the database are inserting or updating data using code blocks.

```
User.insert(message_chat_id=msg_chat_id, mail=data) \
            .on_conflict(
                conflict_target=[User.message_chat_id],
                update={User.mail: data}) \
            .execute()
```

Comment: Seems like the problem is in `update={User.mail: data})` and SQLite doesn't support that type of thing. Are you using SQLite localy?

Comment: @sudden_appearance so but this code working in my pc and working very good. Maybe it's the version of the peewee?

Comment: Your sqlite is almost certainly too old. Try compiling it yourself or using pysqlite3-binary.

Comment: @coleifer I still don't know python well, so I don't understand what you mean, I decided to rewrite the part related to peewee and sqlite. Everything works now. I use sqlite3 module and standard sql requests